# Get substring from string date using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string "Date.2014.07.04"

Then if I want to get "07" from string above using regex.

How do I do that?

I don't want to use split.

Why I don't want to use split? Because when we split, the result will be in array of string. And usually we'll try to get the index of array that we want. In my case it will be

```
var date = "Date.2014.07.04";
date.Split('.')[2];
```

But let say we update the date to new string (Remove all '.').

```
var date = "Date20140704";
date.Split('.')[2];
```

This will throw an error because it can't find index number 2.

By using regex, this error won't occur and it will just return empty string if the pattern that we want can't be found inside string. :)

Comment: Split and get the 3rd element?

Comment: I'm with @Jerry Regex isn't the easiest thing in the word to deal with and if it's always going to be this format, then you can do String.split('.')[2] (Sorry if syntax isn't perfect on that)

Comment: fwiw, the best way to do this is to use one of date.parse family of functions and then take the Month property.

Comment: Why do you not want to use split?

Comment: And may I know why you don't want it?

Comment: @DanDrews I put the reason why I don't want to use split :)

Comment: @IhsanMuhammad Well, a regex will not work if you update to new string either... it won't find any match and you'll get an empty string or something like that.

Comment: @Jerry yes exactly, at least this won't throw any exception which will make the system fail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
"Date.2014.07.04".Split('.')[2];
```

Since you are insisting on Regex, do this:

```
var value = Regex.Match("Date.2014.07.04",@"(?<=\w{4}\.\d{4}\.)\d+").Value
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you ;)

Comment: I put the reason why I don't want to use split :)

Comment: @IhsanMuhammad, well, in that case my regex wont work

Comment: Yes, I will know that this doesn't work when it returns empty string. Instead of throwing an error while we use split. Btw thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You better parse the date and then get the desired part using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but you have to remove `Date.` from the date string first.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate.Replace("Date.",""), "yyyy.MM.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int month = dt.Month;
```

You can also use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

```
string month =  strDate.Split('.')[2];
```

Comment: That's pretty neat that you can define a term ('Date') that the ParseExact method will expect, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

It is a good advvice to use a datetime function like `ParseExact` or `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` etc since it will validate each part as well. But if you really need regex, have a look at this one, it will validate month part as well:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\.\d{2}$
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/w4ds0cbMV5)